# Are there any way to optimize tabulator tree expand with a lot of children?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to use tabulator tree to display some hierarchical data and been loving it.

Now, my data has a lot of children nodes, and because of that, when expanding the parent node, it will be really slow. Here's the fiddle to better describe the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/RonaldoC/m9gdwz86/29/

Try to click one of the parent node.

I'm using this part of code to simulate the data (so level 1 has 5 node, each of them has 10000 children node, and each of that children node has about 100 nodes)

```
let treeData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let level1Data = {
    name: "Data with a lot of Children",
    data: "Something"
  };
  let level1Children = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    let level2Data = {
      name: "Data Children level 2",
      data: "Something",
    };
    let level2Children = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
      let level3Data = {
        name: "Data Children level 3",
        data: "Something"
      };
      level2Children.push(level3Data);
    }
    level2Data._children = level2Children;
    level1Children.push(level2Data);
  }
  level1Data._children = level1Children;
  treeData.push(level1Data);
}
```

Are there any way to optimize it?
I tried to look into the code, but can't figure out what I can change, it seems to be doing the expand recursively?
Also tried to read the docs for any "optimization configuration", but no luck there either.

Thanks!

Comment: You might try to un-nest your data with 5 million entries in it. That's a lot of DOM elements to create! It looks like tabulator has some callbacks you can use to see when the row is expanded.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz would you mind to elaborate more on what do you mean by "un-nest"? are you trying to say to not use tree structure? because I need the data to be in a tree structure (that's the main requirement).

Comment: as Calculuswhiz says 5 million children is a huge amount of data to load into a table and is the reason the table is struggling. There would be no meaningful way any of your users could absorb that much data from a table, so it might be worth considering how to better display it.

Comment: @OliFolkerd hmm the real data is actually about 400k in total, I'm just using the max number of children for each level from my real data. But yeah as I said, one of the actual user requirement is to have expand and collapse for the columns available in the DB with that huge amount of data, that's why I go with tree table.

Comment: at that point i would suggest loading the tree children in over ajax when the row is expanded